# MSE reputation on my resume

Tags: discussion, reputation

Though my reputation isn't that high, can I still put it on my resume while applying for an admission in a premier Mathematical Institute?

Does having a good reputation on MSE counts as an achievement to be put on a resume?

Comment: [This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/stack-overflow-reputation-in-cv) might be relevant.

Comment: A related question on Academia site: [How to communicate achievements on the StackExchange network in an academic CV or job interview?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1658)
This post here on meta is also to some extent related: [What is the Real Use of Reputation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3609)

Comment: I am not sure that $400$ is above average, but if you are applying for a position where teaching skills are important, and if you feel that you have made nice contributions here, then I'd say that it could be relevant, in a section further down the end of your resume.

Comment: Given that 245 of your 400 reputation points came from *[having asked one question]* about "visualization of the 4th dimension", leaving a gain of a net 155 from answers, I would personally advise you not to include, as an "asset"on your CV, your rep from MSE.  However, if you are a highschool student, seeking admission into a math program, then it would be appropriate, in you personal statement, to include mention of extra-curricula activity on MSE, how it's helped, or honed, or clarified or deepened your appreciation for math.

Comment: Oops, I intended to link [the 245 reputation question you asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/445058/idea)

Answer (score 7):

Considering the majority of questions asked and answered on the site, it would be more appropriate to mention your reputation when applying for admission to a premier (pre-)calculus course.

Comment: Seconding this. Including the rep *per tag* may help the OP. Not sure about that either.

Comment: haha! this made me laugh. Honest, but a little mean